# Enable Mapbox Draw control programmatically

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl, mapbox-gl-draw

Using Mapbox-gl-draw (https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-draw)

I am able to get the basic example up and running, and this package does everything I need. However, I am having trouble figuring out how to activate the draw functionality programatically. For example, my application has some panel overlays, and as part of a form I'd like to activate the draw ability by clicking a custom button, not the control button that shows on the map. Ideally I'd like to keep the map control button hidden (which I can do).

I've scoured the documentation with no luck. Anyone have any insight?

Demo of the functionality I am referring to here: https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/mapbox-gl-draw/

Comment: Maybe provide the answer you've got on GitHub (https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-draw/issues/794#issuecomment-395255365) also here?

Answer (score 3):

It's documented in the [API reference](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-draw/blob/master/docs/API.md#changemodemode-string-options-object-draw)

`changeMode(mode: string, options?: Object): draw`

Changes Draw to another mode. Returns the draw instance for chaining.